# Basic bet profit calcuation with probability

Tags: probability

Imagine a bet system: 
there is a stake of 7.10 (entry cost)
there is a payout of  12.83 (winnings)
the probability is given at 0.553059108

I can adjust the payout (the stake is then calculated via the probability). The above values give a profit of  5.74 (rounded). However, given that probability is fixed, and I can set the payout, what is the formula to calculate the stake I must set if I want a target profit of 8?

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy:

```
stake = profit / (1 - probability)
```

> 8 / (1 - 0.553) = 17.897